# In JMX, can I get a specific MBeanAttributeInfo directly?

Tags: java, jmx

Is there any way to, without additional libraries, get the `MBeanAttributeInfo` of a specific attribute directly, as opposed to using `MBeanInfo.getAttributes()` and doing a linear search through it?

Example scenario: check whether a given attribute - `jboss:service=Mail.State` in the example - is writable.

```
MBeanServer server; // Assume this is initialized somewhere else

MBeanAttributeInfo[] infos = server.getMBeanInfo(new ObjectName("jboss:service=Mail"));
for(MBeanAttributeInfo info : infos) {
    if(info.getName().equals("State")) {
        if(info.isWritable()) {
            //do something
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

What I'm hoping to find is something like a `getAttributeInfo(ObjectName name, String attribute)` method in the `MBeanServer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by:

```
server.getAttribute(new ObjectName("jboss:service=Mail"), "State")
```

where server is a MBeanServerConnection and "State" is the attribute name.

Comment: Thank you, but what I need is the `MBeanAttributeInfo`, not the value of the attribute.